# Images doesn´t appear in storyboard Corona SDK

Tags: lua, storyboard, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I am doing a game in corona SDK, but I have this little problem.

I have a menu with a button. If I press it, it sends me to the first level of my game.
When I pass the final level, the game return me to the menu. Bur, if I start playing the first again, my images doesn´t appear.

The images are balls, and to pass the level, you have to eliminate all the balls. To do this, I use:

ball:removeSlef()
ball = nil

But, I don´t think that this is the problem, because I eliminate this lines, and it doesn´t work.
The images are create in scene:createScene function, and insert in the Group.

I short the code of the first level to be understood.

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

local physics = require "physics"
physics.start(); physics.pause()

physics.setGravity( 0, 0 )

local cont = 0
local bur = {}

function eliminar1( event )
        if (cont == 0) and (event.phase == "began") then
                event.target:removeSelf()
                bur[1] = nil
                cont = cont + 1
        end
 end
function eliminar2( event )
        if (cont == 1) and (event.phase == "began") then
                bur[2]:removeSelf()
                bur[2] = nil
                cont = cont + 1
        end
 end
function eliminar3( event )
        if (cont == 2) and (event.phase == "began") then
                bur[3]:removeSelf()
                bur[3] = nil
                storyboard.gotoScene( "levels.1.level2" )
        end
end

function scene:createScene ( event )
        local screenGroup = self.view

        for i = 1,3 do
                bur[i] = display.newImage("irudiak/"..i..".png")
                bur[i]:translate(math.random(0,280), math.random(0,400) )
                physics.addBody( bur[i], {bounce = 0.3 } )
                bur[i]:setLinearVelocity(math.random(-50,50), math.random(-50,50) )
                screenGroup:insert(bur[i])     
        end


        bur[1]:addEventListener("touch", eliminar1)
        bur[2]:addEventListener("touch", eliminar2)
        bur[3]:addEventListener("touch", eliminar3)    
end

function scene:enterScene( event )
        local screenGroup = self.view

        physics.start()

end

function scene:exitScene( event )
        local screenGroup = self.view

        physics.stop()

end

function scene:destroyScene( event )
        local screenGroup = self.view

        package.loaded[physics] = nil
        physics = nil
end

return scene
```

Answer (score 0):

`createScene` is ran only first time when you `gotoScene`. Every next time only `willEnterScene` and `enterScene` are played. To play `createScene` again you have to remove it (`storyboard.removeScene()` I guess). Or you can move some stuff you need to `willEnterScene`. For more detailed info you can watch this:  http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/08/20/tutorial-reloading-storyboard-scenes/